# How do I slow down the camera's speed moving through a scene in Babylon js?

Tags: babylonjs

I have added a FreeCamera to a babylon.2.4.js scene and am controlling its movement with this code:

```
this.angularSensibility = 5000;
camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("FreeCamera", new BABYLON.Vector3(-0.6, -5, -20), scene);
camera.keysUp = [84]; // T
camera.keysDown = [66]; // B
camera.keysLeft = [70]; // F
camera.keysRight = [72]; // H
camera.angularSensibility = this.angularSensibility;
camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
```

However it moves the camera very quickly through the scene. How might I set the speed to something less?

http://www.visualdiagnostics.ca/eyemap3Djs/magnify.html

Answer (score 3):

Hello you should just have to reduce camera.speed value

Answer (score 0):

I've found a roundabout way of making movement seem slower simply by increasing the size of the scene. More ground to cover takes longer. However this seems just a hack and not a real solution.

http://www.visualdiagnostics.ca/eyemap3Djs/magnifyBig.html